# Oracle to SQL Server Migration verification

Tags: sql-server, oracle, testing

We are in process of completing the migration of Oracle to SQL Server 2005 (schema, data and programming objects). We have about 1220 stored procedures to be tested. What would be the best way to test them? Is there any automation possible here?

We are thinking of writing a small window tool which would take the stored procedure name and list of parameters, would call the Oracle and SQL Server database and then compare the table table outputs. Although this eases the pain to some extent, it still does not eliminate human intervention and would not test every possible flow for the stored procedures, unless the parameters specified changes the proc flow.

I guess, what i am trying to say is what can we do further to ease the pain!

All and any suggestion/help would be appreciated!!

Thanks,
Atul

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that counts here is the working of the application. So my advice would be to run you application and test you scenarios on both databases containing the same data and see if the results are the same in both cases. When you find errors you will need to zoom into the problems and try to reproduce the problems using simple lower level calls, outside of the application.

I hope this helps,
[Ronald](http://ronr.nl)

Comment: Thanks Ronald. we are in process of doing this. Was wondering if there was a way to automate some part of this. Thanks anyways, appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: MAybe something like pureload or puretest can help?